# CheckPoint Firewall Comand Line Login fwpolicy.exe

Tags: checkpoint-firewall

Is there a way to use command line to login to CheckPoint Smart Dashboard with the fwpolicy.exe tool ? How do I look at the help pages or manpages ?

Comment: What would you like to achieve? SmartDashboard is an interactive tool anyway so what is the reason for non-interactive login? ------ I know that you can specify: management server address, user name and policy name but I am almost sure that you cannot perform the authentication from the command line. ------ Debugging options are in the CLI Reference Guide the other options are not described in the public documentation.

Comment: I would like to automate a login script for use to speed up the process of logging in and remembering passwords.